# Xamarin Studio On Mac - Open SLN and Create Install File

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono

I am trying to make an installer file for mac for my application, and I can't find a way to do this. I am using Xamarin STudio and mono (not monomac), classic windows forms.

So here is what I did:

a)I created in Visual Studio on Windows a hello world app, with a simple window and a button

b)I installed Xamarin Studio in my VMWare mac os X image

c)I open the SLN from windows PC with xamarin studio

Everything is good. The solution opens, if I press run it runs on Mac using mono.
 Now my problem. How do I compile and make the setup for Mac Os X so I can distribute my file (not in the store)?

I tried with right click on solution->tools->create package . But i Have no option to make a mac os x file. How can I do that?

***EDIT
 I managed to compile and run the software on mac. I use the following code:

```
    export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands:$PATH
export AS="as -arch i386"
export CC="cc -arch i386 -lobjc -liconv -framework Foundation"
# Build: --static
mkbundle "/VOLUMES/C/Proiecte/TestMono3/TestMono3/bin/Release/TestMono3.exe" --deps -o hello3
```

When I open hello3, it opens a terminal. Can this be avoided?
 Also, if I don't use --static in mkbundle, can I still distribute the software without the user needing to install mono?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Mono Installer Package (OSX)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324496/create-mono-installer-package-osx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a .app mono bundle for Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862972/how-to-create-a-app-mono-bundle-for-mac-os)

Comment: I read the articles, but I can't find a way to do what I want yet. I want to make an app bundle, that contains ONLY the required mono files (so that the user does not have to install Mono). If anybody has other suggestions, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Do the following:

- Switch your Project to the `Release` configuration from the `Debug` one.
- In the **Build** menu, select **Archive for Publishing**.
- The project will be built, archived and displayed in the **Archive Explorer**.
- Select the desired version of the app and click the **Sign and Distribute** button.
- From the **Sign and Distribute** dialog box, select **Mac Installer Package** and click the **Next** button.
- Fill in the required **Provisioning profile** signing information. *Note: You will have to have an developer account with Apple to correctly sign an installer, even for apps NOT released on the Mac App Store.*
- Continue with the rest of the prompts from the **Sign and Distribute** dialog box to create the installer.

I would suggest reading over the [Publishing to the App Store](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_to_the_app_store/) guide as the steps are basically the same for a self-released installer package.

Comment: He is using "classic windows forms" under Mono, not Xamarin.Mac or MonoMac

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work. "In the Build menu, select Archive for Publishing." is not available. I am using Mono not Xamarin.Mac

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I totally missed the Mono bit. You **should** be able to use any "standard" Mac install builder (there's one that ships with Xcode though I've never used it) as long as you distribute the Mono runtimes and any other used libraries as well. A quick search on the internet should reveal a few good, free install builders.

Comment: My problem is that I am a "noob" with Mac. When I run the project from Xamarin studio, it runs the software, but I can't see any file created (dmg or app, or what extension). When I hit build, same thing, in the bin debug folder I only see the windows exe created in Visual Studio